# Visual Studio 2015 commits automatically after "Add solution to source control"

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015 community edition.
After update 3, if I create a new solution and choose "Add solution to source control", the git plugin automatically commits the current status.
This is sometimes unwanted, as I might want to add more entries to .gitignore before the first commit, and prevent polluting my project with generated or library files. Is there any setting to prevent this behavior?
This behavior was not observed in update 2.
I know I can solve my problems with the git command line.
I have an existing workaround: Create an empty solution, add it to source control, and then start adding the real projects.

Comment: Is there an option "Check in everything when closing a solution or project" or something similar and is it checked?

Comment: I can't find anything like that!